# lodash find returns only one result

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js

I'm using lodash find, and on my test, it is only returning one result, is this the expected response? how to find all instances?

```
var users = [
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 28, gender: "male" },
    { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", age: 5, gender: "female" },
    { firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Carrey", age: 54, gender: "male" },
    { firstName: "Kate", lastName: "Winslet", age: 40, gender: "female" }
  ];

  var encontre = _.find(users, { lastName: "Doe" })

  console.log("usuario encontre::", encontre)
```

response

> usuario encontre:: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 28,
> gender: 'male' }

so how to seethe 2 users with lastName: Doe?

thanks

Comment: use _.filter instead of _.find

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `_.filter` as `_.find` returns the first matched element.
`_.filter` will return an array of all matched elements.

```
var users = [
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 28, gender: "male" },
    { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", age: 5, gender: "female" },
    { firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Carrey", age: 54, gender: "male" },
    { firstName: "Kate", lastName: "Winslet", age: 40, gender: "female" }
  ];

  var encontre = _.filter(users, { lastName: "Doe" })

  console.log("usuario encontre::", encontre)
```

jsfiddle for ref : https://jsfiddle.net/c_Dhananjay/b6ngxhvp/